# How can 'loss function' be translated?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

> In mathematical optimization, statistics, decision theory and machine
>   learning, a loss function or cost function is a function that maps an
>   event or values of one or more variables onto a real number
>   intuitively representing some "cost" associated with the event.

Source: [Loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_function) on Wikipedia

Sagt man tatsächlich "Verlustfunktion" wie z.B. auf [statsoft.de](http://www.statsoft.de/glossary/L/LossFunction.htm)?

Duden.de kennt "Verlustfunktion" jedenfalls nicht.

Comment: The Duden neither does nor should nor intends to contain special technical terms. You will find that it does not contain several mathematical terms, e.g., *Eigenvektor,* to give a prominent example.

Comment: What about *Kostenfunktion* ?

Comment: Both terms "Kostenfunktion" and "Verlustfunktion" are in use. The former one is way more common. I think it depends on "how you look at it". And, apart, "Verlustfunktion" sounds quite a bit negative.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Wrzlprmft. Duden is not the right place to look for specialized terms of a certain scientific field.

Here are some references where *Verlustfunktion* is used for *loss function* in either economic or mathematical context:

- [Stabilitätspolitik: theoretische Grundlagen und institutionelle Alternativen:](http://books.google.de/books?id=uBNgq2MKzYYC&pg=PA12&lpg=PA12&dq=Verlustfunktion&source=bl&ots=YV_CP-xdO1&sig=Wz0AGJ0Z4UDiJQLc6brtb7fxlbE&hl=de&sa=X&ei=xDd_U9biBeXQ4QSIhoDoCA&ved=0CC4Q6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=Verlustfunktion&f=false)
- [Mathe-Skript der Uni Münster](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/statistik/loewe/mathstatistik.pdf)